# Given the inverse of a 2x2 block matrix, find the inverse of a specific block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

I have a block matrix and its inverse:

$$M=\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}, M^{-1}=\pmatrix{E&F\\G&H}$$

I want to compute $A^{-1}$ from $M^{-1}$ ideally without involving any other inversion operations. As far as I can tell this seems infeasible. What I have tried is writing out the equations:

$$MM^{-1}=\pmatrix{AE+BG&AF+BH\\CE+DG&CF+DH} = \pmatrix{I&0\\0&I}$$
$$M^{-1}M=\pmatrix{EA+FC&EB+FD\\GA+HC&GB+HD} = \pmatrix{I&0\\0&I}$$

But all of those result in some inverse when I try to compute $A^{-1}$. Can someone confirm that this is indeed infeasible? If this helps, I can constrain this to $M$ and $M^{-1}$ being real symmetric matrices.

Comment: As $A$ appears always as product with other matrices in these formulas, it seems to be impossible to compute $A^{-1}$ if the inverses of $E$, $F$ are not known a-priori.

Answer (score 1):

Just because $M$ is invertible, $A$ doesn’t have to. Consider for example the $2\times 2$-matrix
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

I didn’t yet think about what happens, if we *assume* $A$ to be invertible though.

Comment: I assume $A$ and $D$ to be invertible. You can assume further that $M$ is symmetric. I have been trying for a while to find an expression for $A^{-1}$ that does not include any inverses of blocks, but without much success.